# Ionic facebook login invalid key hash. The key hash (key) does not match any stored key hashes

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, ionic2, facebook-login

I would like to use facebook login.

I did everything, I did use this code and I put to returned code in facebook developers key hashes

```
keytool -exportcert -alias androiddebugkey -keystore %HOMEPATH%\.android\debug.keystore | openssl sha1 -binary | openssl
base64
```

but still return this error;

[image: Error image]

If error image doest open ; invalid key hash.

The key hash (key) does not match any stored key hashes.

Configure your app key hashes at ......

How can I fix this error

Comment: As the error say. Your key is not match. You need to generate correct keyhash and config to your app

Answer (score 1):

copy the key that appears in the error message in the hash key field then save and normally it should go

Answer (score 0):

i've the same error.

i'm using;

```
keytool -exportcert -alias alias.keystore -keystore YOUR_RELEASE_KEY_PATH | openssl sha1 -binary | openssl base64
```

after that i just copied the hash and then paste in to the developer.facebook settings.

thanks